# How to change Eclipse Preferences programmatically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

What approach should be to change Eclipse Preferences?

[They are stored in `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugin/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431989/where-does-eclipse-store-preferences)

But I hope to find Java API and a way to discover any preference ID.

Comment: Looked at Eclipse plugins?  The M2 plugin can set a lot of project settings, it might inspire.  What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Is this for a plugin that you are writing or are you trying to change existing preferences of other plugins?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somewhat confusingly there are several APIs a plugin can use for preferences.

If your plugin activator extends `AbstractUIPlugin` then you can call

```java
IPreferenceStore prefStore = getPreferenceStore();
```

in the activator to get the preference store for your plugin.

You can also use

```java
IEclipsePreferences prefs = InstanceScope.INSTANCE.getNode("node id");
```

to get a slightly different interface to the preferences.

There is also the `org.eclipse.equinox.preferences.preferences` extension point which lets you define an 'initializer' to set the default values for preferences.